# Creating JS objects and dynamically accessing their data on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

I am creating a series of horizontally sliding menus. A brief overview: you have items `A,B,C,D,E`, and the menu only shows `BCD`. Press `<-` to change view to `ABC`, or press `->` to change view to `CDE`, etc. The item count is variable, so some will be `ABCD`, some might be `ABCDEF`.

I figured creating objects would be better than hard-coding these individually.

Here is my code:

```
function Slider(uniqueName, subtitles, icons, descripts, links){
    var thisSlider = '#'+uniqueName; //in this example uniqueName = 'mbp'
    $(thisSlider).html('<div class="sliderContainer" id="'+uniqueName+'">\
            <div class="sliderArrowContainer">\
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="matSliderLeft"><img class="sliderLeft" id="'+uniqueName+'Left" src="../images/misc/lArrowGrey.png"></a>\
            </div>\
            <div class="sliderBlock">\
                <div class="sliderIconHolder"><img class="sliderImg" src="../images/misc/'+icons[0]+'"></div>\
                <div class="sliderSubtitle">'+subtitles[0]+'</div>\
                <div class="sliderText">'+descripts[0]+'</div>\
            </div>\
            <div class="sliderBlock">\
                <div class="sliderIconHolder"><img class="sliderImg" src="../images/misc/'+icons[1]+'"></div>\
                <div class="sliderSubtitle">'+subtitles[1]+'</div>\
                <div class="sliderText">'+descripts[1]+'</div>\
            </div>\
            <div class="sliderBlock">\
                <div class="sliderIconHolder"><img class="sliderImg" src="../images/misc/'+icons[2]+'"></div>\
                <div class="sliderSubtitle">'+subtitles[2]+'</div>\
                <div class="sliderText">'+descripts[2]+'</div>\
            </div>\
            <div class="sliderArrowContainer">\
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="matSliderRight"><img id="'+uniqueName+'Right" src="../images/misc/rArrowGreen.png"></a>\
            </div>\
        </div>');
    $(uniqueName).data( { subtitles: [subtitles], icons: [icons], descripts: [descripts], links:[links] } );

}


$(".sliderLeft").live("click", function() {
    var cur = this.id;
    cur = cur.substr(0,3); //this is bc all var uniqueNames are 3char, in this case it is 'mbp'
    var tempData = $('#'+cur).data(subtitles[0]);
    alert(tempData); //this alerts undefined
});
```

**My alert at the end alerts undefined**. Obviously something in my syntax is very wrong, but I'm also wondering if my approach in general is wrong? The vars passed into `Slider();` are arrays (aside from `uniqueName`), so I'm trying to store the arrays using jQuery `.data();` into the main container.

Any help on how to store multiple arrays being passed to `Slider();` into `.sliderContainer`, and then accessing it by obtaining the `.sliderContainer`'s ID by clicking on different parts... would be very helpful.

(Should I be using JSON?)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure what you want to do is:

```
var tempData = $('#'+cur).data('subtitles')[0];
```

You're accessing the data property `subtitles` which you know to be an array, and you want the first element. The above code does none of the checking and validation that it should.

Also, this bit:

```
$(uniqueName).data( ...
```

You should have used `thisSlider` as the unique name does not include the hash. Change to

```
$(thisSlider).data( ...
```

Comment: This still doesn't work -- `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`. Thank you, though.

Comment: Looks like there may be a problem where I'm assigning data, will look into it -- your syntax has helped me in alerting test data in the console :)

Comment: @HC_ - if you create a http://www.jsfiddle.net of what you're trying to do then its easier to guide you in the right direction on a better approach

Comment: So your syntax correction was half the mistake, the other half was missing a `'#'` in the data assignment @__________@ thank you for your help!